# How to write LINQ for this data

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

I'm in the process of converting a very old asp page into apsx. The data is in an Oracle DB. I've already run a select on it and loaded it into a data table. The select I used is from the previous asp page. It looks like this:

```
select StepId,d.name,c.requisitionentryid,c.requisitionid, NVL(a.starteddate,'') as submitdate, 
NVL(c.closeddate,'') as closeddate,c.STATUSID,
(Select b.FirstName || ' ' || b.LastName as UserName from DirPerson b where A.ownerid = b.PERSONID ) 
as Initiator,
(Select b.FirstName || ' ' || b.LastName as UserName from DirPerson b where A.CUSTOMERID = 
b.PERSONID) as Customer,
TxActivity.ActivityID        as ActivityID,
TxActivity.CustomerID        as CustomerID,
TxActivity.PerformerID       as PerformerID,
TxActivity.ActivityTypeId       as ActivityTypeId,
NVL(TxActivity.CompletedOn,'')   as approvercompletedon,
TxActivity.TicketObjectID    as TicketObjectID,
(select FirstName          from DirPerson where PersonID=TxActivity.PerformerID )  as 
ApproverFirstName,
(select LastName           from DirPerson where PersonID=TxActivity.PerformerID ) as 
ApproverLastName, 
e.COMPLETEDACTIONID,NVL(TxActivity.Startedon,'') as Startedon 

from txrequisition A,txrequisitionentry c,defservice d, TxActivity, txactivityassignment e 
where " + Where + "  and a.requisitionid = c.requisitionid and TxActivity.ActivityID  = 
e.ActivityID(+) and c.serviceid = d.serviceid

and c.RequisitionEntryID=TxActivity.TicketID and TxActivity.TicketObjectID=37
and ((TxActivity.StepId =5 or TxActivity.StepId =4 or TxActivity.StepId =0))
```

Eventually I want the data to look something like this:
[image: Example]

The current data structure in the table is you have 2 rows for that single requisition. One for each Approver so my LINQ query looks like this:

```
                    var distinctIds = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    id = s.Field<decimal>("Requisition"),
                    Name = s.Field<string>("Service Name"),
                    Initiator = s.Field<string>("Initiator"),
                    Customer = s.Field<string>("Customer"),
                    SubmitDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(s.Field<DateTime>("SubmitDate"), cstZone),
                    ClosedDate = s.Field<DateTime?>("ClosedDate") == null ? "": TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(s.Field<DateTime>("ClosedDate"), cstZone).ToString(),
                    Status = s.Field<decimal>("StatusId") == 1 ? "Ongoing" :
                            s.Field<decimal>("StatusId") == 2 ? "Closed" :
                            s.Field<decimal>("StatusId") == 3 ? "Cancelled" :
                            s.Field<decimal>("StatusId") == 4 ? "Rejected" : "?",
                    Approvers = "....",

                })
                .Distinct().ToList();
```

I've run into a problem on how to get the Approvers. Is the best way to write a sub select for the approvers in the current LINQ statement? If so, what would it look like?

Would a better method be to rewrite the original query?

thanks,

lee

Comment: What if you used a `GroupBy` to group the two rows and then did a select on each group?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Didn't think of that.Thanks!